# SSH permission denied (publickey) - Laravel Forge

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, digital-ocean, laravel-forge

I have followed Jeffrey Way's [instructions](https://laracasts.com/series/server-management-with-forge/episodes/4) and I am continuously getting the same SSH error within Terminal.

I am wanting to connect through Sequel Pro and upon digging further into it, this is the most accurate log description:

```
debug1: Host 'IP ADDRESS' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/ben/.ssh/known_hosts:17
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/ben/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/ben/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I generate my SSH key this way:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your_email@example.com"
```

Then copy it into Laravel Forge by:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | pbcopy
```

It saves without error. But then I try forge@ip_address and it returns the Permission denied error, always.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by recreating the server on Forge. `pbcopy` also failed to work.

Comment: you have to pay a new server when you create a new server in Forge -.-'

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem follwing the instructions.

Try:

```
pbcopy < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Answer (score 1):

If you added your key from the Forge "Account" > "SSH keys" page **after** creating your server, you'll need to also add your key here:

- Servers > [your server name] > SSH keys > Add